# Custom Active Link in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to add active class which router is active in react. I start learning react so i need some help in this. 
I need to add the class in the **li** element not on the **Link** element.

```
<ul className="list-unstyled">
    <li className={RouteHelper("/")}> <Link to="/"> <FaHome /> Home </Link> </li>
    <li className={RouteHelper("/tables")}><Link to="tables"> <FaTable />Tables </Link></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the function which is getting active class

```
const RouteHelper = (url) => {
    return window.location.pathname === url ? "active" : null;
}
export default RouteHelper;
```

Comment: Use `NavLink`. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string

Comment: What is the issue you're facing ?

Comment: Navlink also add class to Navlink element i need to add on the li element

Comment: I want to add the class to li element. Navlink or link i don't want to add the class to those items.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? It looks like it would append the right className to the li tags.

Comment: Yeah it add the class name when page load first time but after that it is not working

Comment: Are you getting any error? Your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: No error encoutered. But className is added on page load after that is not working while we change navigation or route.

Comment: Hmm, I'm writing out an answer for you now. Last question, is this going to be in a navbar, like is the navbar there the entire time?

Comment: Have you added routes for them?

Comment: Navbar is loaded just first time. And after that only route is changed thorugh router

Comment: @ravibagul91 yeah i already added. <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
              <Route path="/tables" component={Tables} exact />
            </Switch>

Comment: What you are getting when you click on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to create a CustomLink.
Here is the code from the react-router [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link).

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomLinkExample = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <ListItemLink activeOnlyWhenExact={true} to="/">
            <FaHome /> Home
          </ListItemLink>
          <ListItemLink activeOnlyWhenExact={true} to="/tables" label="Tables">
            <FaTable />
            Tables
          </ListItemLink>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/tables" component={Tables} exact />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const ListItemLink = ({ to, activeOnlyWhenExact, children }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={to}
      exact={activeOnlyWhenExact}
      children={({ match }) => (
        <li className={match ? 'active' : ''}>
          <Link to={to}>{children}</Link>
        </li>
      )}
    />
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

const Tables = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouter-62rye

Answer (score 0):

```
//At first you can create a css style.it is applied in the react router v6.

const navLinkStyles = ({isActive})=>{
        return{
            color:isActive?'lightgreen':'white',
            fontWeight:isActive?'bold': 'normal'}}

//Then apply this css in link

   
<NavLink as={Link} to='/manage' style={navLinkStyles} className="hidden md:block mx-5 text-gray-300  hover:text-white" >Manage Items</NavLink>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).